# Proving $\tan \frac{\alpha}{2}\tan \frac{\beta}{2} \tan \frac{\gamma}{2} \le \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

Hello I need with this problem:
$tan \frac{\alpha}{2}\tan \frac{\beta}{2} \tan \frac{\gamma}{2} \le \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$ 
$\alpha,  \beta, \gamma,  $ are angles in acute triangle. I tried using $\tan x$ series expansions, formula for tangent of half angle. I also know that $\tan a \tan b \tan c = \tan a + \tan b + \tan c$ ,
but other than that I don't know how to approach this problem, thanks for help.

Comment: Hint: $\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}$
$\tan\frac{\beta}{2} +
\tan\frac{\beta}{2}
\tan\frac{\gamma}{2} +
\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}
\tan\frac{\alpha}{2} = 1$

Comment: thank you for the hint, but I don't see how I can use it in this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\tan{\frac{a}{2}}\cdot \tan{\frac{b}{2}}\cdot \tan{\frac{c}{2}}\leq \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$, Where a,b,c are angles of triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319746/tan-fraca2-cdot-tan-fracb2-cdot-tan-fracc2-leq-frac13) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Ctan%5Cfrac%7B%5Calpha%7D%7B2%7D%5Ctan%5Cfrac%7B%5Cbeta%7D%7B2%7D%5Ctan%5Cfrac%7B%5Cgamma%7D%7B2%7D%5Cle%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%24&p=1). There are also several AoPS threads, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [X,Y,Z find out](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1156279p5487619) and [trigonometric identity..... isi 2012 #1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h479431p2684429). Finally, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: oh thank you, I couldn't find it, I'll delete this question then